# Open-source Java data manipulation software

Tags: open-source, java

I am looking for open-source Java software that allows the user to interactively manipulate/transform large amounts of data and these manipulations usually follow some sort of pattern.

Two examples of what I mean would be a spreadsheet with a pattern such as (sort -> filter), or an image manipulation program with a common pattern such as (bevel -> emboss -> smooth).

I am not specifically interested in what these patterns would be, just software that has common usage paths and these paths are not trivial i.e. there is some computation required at each step.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend [Pentaho Data Integration](http://www.pentaho.com/product/data-integration).

- Allows you to model a transformation with many different kinds of steps
- Easy to understand visual interface
- Sort, filter, and many other steps.
- Open Source
- In Java

[image]

Not sure about steps for images, though. It is more about rows of textual/numerical data.